# Finding header value in xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datatable, linq-to-xml

Here my xml is setup as follows:
This is coming via a webservice.

```
<doc>
<str name="data_id">XXXXXXX</str>
<str name="data">YYYY</str>
<str name="data2">zzzz</str>
...
..
<doc>

<doc>
<str name="data_id">X1X1X1X1X1X1X1</str>
<str name="data">Y1Y1Y1Y1</str>
<str name="data2">z1z1z1z1</str>
...
..
<doc>
```

I am converting the whole xml into a datatable.

How do I get the column header as column attributes. 
The resulting datatable have to be in the format as

```
data_id   data
xxxxx     yyyy
```

After loading xmldocument I have the following code which I have written to convert the whole thing into a csv string.

```
Stream k = r.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
string csvOut = string.Empty;
var doc = XDocument.Load(k);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100000);
DataTable table1 = new DataTable();

foreach (XElement node in doc.Descendants("doc"))
{
    foreach (XElement innerNode in node.Elements())
    {

        sb.AppendFormat("{0},", innerNode.Value);
    }
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
    sb.AppendLine();
}
csvOut = sb.ToString();
```

I am trying to get the headers as data_id , data etc

Comment: First - you should provide more of your XML. It's now not clear how data for different rows should look like. Second - show your current attempt

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Sure. I have edited my question with the details.

Answer (score 3):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// Get all column names from document
var columnNames = xdoc.Root.Descendants("str")
                      .Select(s => (string)s.Attribute("name"))
                      .Distinct();

// create column for each unique str
foreach(var columnName in columnNames)
   dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(columnName));

foreach(var doc in xdoc.Root.Elements("doc"))
{
   var row = dt.NewRow();

   // fill row values
   foreach(var str in doc.Elements("str"))
       row[(string)str.Attribute("name")] = (string)str;

   dt.Rows.Add(row); // add row
}
```

If all docs contain exactly same set of `str` elements, then you can replace column names getting with

```
var columName = xdoc.Root.Element("doc").Elements("str")
                    .Select(s => (string)s.Attribute("name"));
```

That will read only first `<doc>` node instead of traversing all elements in xml document.

Comment: Thanks. I got the idea. Can you advise how can I have a grasp on linq. I am currently working with a lot of these xml parsing and having trouble. Thanks

Comment: @fuller if you have lot of time, then I suggest you to dig into Jon's series [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects](http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/index.html) also there is excellent tutorial on pluralsight [LINQ Fundamentals](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/linq-fundamentals)

Comment: I have a follow up question relating to the question i asked. What if I have some elements in array in the xml instead of str in the beginning like  <arr name="genomic_id"><str>homosapiens</str></arr>. Do I have to look for those elements in a separate loop after i look for only str elements. Or is there a standard implementation you would do. In short if the doc tag has more than one types of elements.

Comment: @fuller you need to handle that manually. You will need to read `arr` elements instead of `str` elements for getting column names and finding row values. But you don't need separate loop, because there is single `str` element inside `arr` element. Just get value as `row[(string)arr.Attribute("name")] = (string)arr.Element("str");`

Answer (score 0):

Here is just a hint how you should do it with XDocument and LINQ.

```
    var query = from c in xmlFile.Descendants("doc") select c;
string data_id;
string data;
Datatable dt = new Datatable();
DataRow row;

foreach (XElement dom in query)
            {
            data_id = dom.Element("data_id").Value;
            data = dom.Element("data").Value;


  row = dt.NewRow();
  row[0] = data_id;
  row[1] = data;
  dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

Comment: Actually want to get the string "data_id" from the document. I already have the value for the data_id field in my csv.